# What can I assume in this proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I know that in this question I'm supposed to let f, g, a, and b all be arbitrary. Can I assume that $f''$ and $g''$ exist?
[image]

Comment: Yes, because $f$ and $g$ are in the family $A.$

Comment: Well, the existence of the second derivative is part of the conditions for being in the set $A$, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f,g\in A \implies f'',g''$ exist, and $(f'' + f) = (g''+g) = 0$

$q = af+bg$

Differentiation is a "linear operator"

$q'' = af'' + bg''\\
q + q'' = a(f + f'') + b(g+g'')\\
q+ q'' = 0\\
q+ q'' \in A$